# How to add new calculated column in a dataframe using python

Tags: python

This may be a novice question however,I've spent couple of hours figuring out how to do this.
Okie, I have a data frame with 150 variables and a target . sample as below:

```
train
Out[1]: 
        var1  var2    target
0          A      C      10.5   
1          A      D      13.5          
2          B      D      2.5
```

I'd like to crate new dataframe with added column which has the mean of target.
eg row1 of var1_new should have mean of target where var1 ==A i.e 12  ((10.5+13.5)/2)

I'm unable to figure this out in python.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
train_new
Out[2]: 
          var1   var2  target    var1_new   var2_new   
0          A      C      10.5       12       10.5             
1          A      D      13.5       12        8       
2          B      D      2.5        2.5       8
```

Comment: Please provide code snippet

Comment: @Nim J, please be more clear on what you want.  do you want the means of 2 columns to be in a third column.  You give an example of (12.5+13.5)/2, yet there is no number 12.5 in your data.  Are var1 and var2 numeric, and would those be the columns you want the mean from, or the mean from one of them with the target making 2 new columns?

Comment: Apologies @ivan7707. i corrected it. The new variables should have mean value of target. Var1 and Var2 are categorical.

Comment: @Nim J, I don't get it, if you have target, how to you get 2 new columns to come up with the mean?  Are you trying to get the mean of rows 0 and 1 to be the column var1_new value?  I can't imagine why you would want this, but your example shows the wrong calc in row 1/var1_new.  Or, if you want to get 2 numbers var_1 and var_2 to be the mean of target, then there are and endless # of possibilities.

Comment: @ivan7707 : okie lemme be specific. the mean I need is of target column. for eg, if you filter var1 and select A, the mean of target would be 12 and if you select B, mean value of target is 2.5 .likewise if we filter var2 and select D , mean value of target would be 8 . Further since i've 150+ variables in my dataframe, i need python code help on automating column name creation as well as on the calculation

Comment: @Nim J, ok, understood.  update you question to clarify this.  look into the groupby and mean for dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
variables = ['var1', 'var2']
for var in variables:
    df[var + "_new"] = None

for var in variables:
    for k, v in df.groupby(var).mean()['target'].iteritems():
        df.loc[df[var] == k, var + "_new"] = v
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ilya V. Schurov  . This works. Please change items() to iteritems(), as we are iterating through a pandas series.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that at least in Python 3 `pd.Series.items()` and `pd.Series.iteritems()` do the same thing (produce iterator), but documentation mention only `iteritems()`. Okay, I replaced it. You can accept and answer if it solves your problem by clicking on the checkmark to the left.